# Запросы с использованием куки

Tags: c#

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("uno.site.com?redirect=duo.site.com");
```

сервер задаёт куку и происходит редирект.

```
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

получаем содержимое страницы "duo.site.com". в содержимом сервер читает куку, и выдаёт уникальный для этой куки текст.
но куки уже нет... она пришла, но куда-то пропала, из-за чего сервер читает куку, и ничего не выводит

Comment: [Свойство HttpWebRequest.CookieContainer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer(v=vs.110).aspx): _For security reasons, **cookies are disabled by default**. If you want to use cookies, use the CookieContainer property to enable cookies._

Comment: @Grundy thanks, but how can i do it? request.CookieContainer=true;?

Comment: Это была цитата, поэтому по-английски :) по ссылке в предыдущем комментарии есть пример с этим свойством

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо большое!!! Марсианин, я землянин. Объясни, почему ты такой дельный ответ написал в комментарий?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, готово!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для хранения кук в [HttpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=VS.95).aspx) используется [свойство HttpWebRequest.CookieContainer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer(v=vs.110).aspx).

> For security reasons, cookies are disabled by default. If you want to use cookies, use the CookieContainer property to enable cookies.

> По соображениям безопасности, по умолчанию куки отключены. Если вы хотите использовать их, используйте свойство CookieContainer.

По умолчанию значение этого свойства `null`. Поэтому нужно присвоить этому свойству объект CookieContainer.

[Пример использования из MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer(v=vs.110).aspx#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B):

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(args[0]);
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(); // инициализируем свойство

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

// Print the properties of each cookie.
foreach (Cookie cook in response.Cookies)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Cookie:");
    // Show the string representation of the cookie.
    Console.WriteLine ("String: {0}", cook.ToString());
}
```